# Run Pandas queries on data frame in Dataspell variable viewer

Tags: dataspell

After I run a script in Dataspell, I'm able to go to the variable viewer, "View as DataFrame", have the dataframe pop up in the main view window. But I also want to run Pandas queries on that data frame and have it display the result as a dataframe. Is this possible?